# Error inserting data into MySQL Table via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a MySQL database with a table "AllParties". When I INSERT data into that table using PHP (below) I don't get an error, however, the data is not inserted into the table. I tried getting an error report from the MySQL server and, rather ambiguously, it said there is an error in MySQL Syntax. Please note I'm running my code in Mac CodeRunner, possibly this is the problem? Also, $con is a successful connection.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("sql3.freemysqlhosting.net","*********","********","*********");

$name = "Will's Party";
$date = 'October 1st, 2013';
$housenum = '333 East Street';
$city = "Golden Gate";
$state = "California"; 
$time = "7:00";
$tag = "Serra";

mysqli_select_db('AllParties', $con);

$alpha = mysqli_query($con, 'INSERT INTO AllParties(Party Name, Date, House number and       street name, City, State, Time, Tag)  VALUES("$name","$date","$housenum","$city","$state","$time","$tag")');
?>
```

Comment: Do you consider `'House number and       street name'` a proper column name?

Comment: You have 7 spaces between 'and' and 'street name'. Is this reflected in the column name?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Never** use string interpolation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any column name with spaces in it, and naming columns like that is a great way to make developers very upset, needs to be escaped:

```
INSERT INTO AllParties (`Party Name`, ...)
```

The backticks, not regular quotes, are used for escaping database, table and column names. Regular quotes `'` and `"` are used for strings.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("sql3.freemysqlhosting.net","*********","********","*********");

$name = 'Will\'s Party';
$date = 'October 1st, 2013';
$housenum = '333 East Street';
$city = 'Golden Gate';
$state = 'California'; 
$time = '7:00';
$tag = 'Serra';

mysqli_select_db('AllParties', $con);

$alpha = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO AllParties(`Party Name`, `Date`, `House   number and street name`, `City`, `State`, `Time`, `Tag`)    VALUES('{$name}','{$date}','{$housenum}','{$city}','{$state}','{$time}','{$tag}')");
?>
```

{$x} will eval the x string